# Open Door shower with glass panels causes water to puddle and then leak out the opening

Tags: bathroom, repair, doors, shower, leak

We recently had our tub and shower replaced with two shower heads. Entrance is in the middle with shower heads on each end. There is not a door, only two glass panes on each side. One of the sides puddles up on the curb and then eventually leaks onto the bathroom floor through the entrance. I don't think the contractor understands the problem or knows how to fix.

The shower head angles are in a good place. The water builds up during the shower and then starts to flow out.

We do not want plastic guards on the corners at the bottom. How can we fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The curb should have a backslope. Does it? Did you try adjusting the shower head angle? Proper answers depend on details. A better description with dimensions and/or photographs would be great.

Comment: I don't see how to attach pictures , but I have some.  The shower head angles are in a good place.  The water builds up during the shower and then starts to flow out.  I don't know what a backslope is, sorry!

Comment: @Lara, backslope is having that curb sloped slightly towards the inside of the shower so water will naturally drain towards the shower rather than away.

Comment: ok, thank you.  They came back to add a slope but it is still leaking water. Not as bad.... but still leaking.

Comment: So ,possibly they need to add more slope ?

Comment: Yes. Or shift the doors to the inside of the curb.